# iOS How to exit current app after using UIApplication openURL to launch a browser

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplication, openurl

I am very new to iOS development. The app I need is very simple: just open a web browser and go to a specific URL when my app is launched. So in the delegate file, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I add a line of code:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

The app can open safari and go to google, however when I press the home button and try to open the app again, I got a write screen. I know I must release the resource after I call the browser, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Ray

Comment: You're not expecting Apple to approve this, are you?

Comment: I have no problem with this in the simulator (iOS 4.2 GM).

Comment: @ceejayoz: Apple will definitely not approve this behavior, but this may just be practice or for personal/in-house use.

Comment: I have to make it since the boss said so. I was also wondering why not just go to safari and type the link, but I don't have a choice. What I am doing here is just saving our clients a few seconds to type in the address...

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: It doesn't work on either 4.0 or 4.1 iphone simulators, but it works on ipad 3.2

Comment: @Ray: Try using a method similar to Apple's LaunchMe sample code (using an Alert View before opening the URL): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LaunchMe/Listings/Classes_LaunchMeAppDelegate_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007417-Classes_LaunchMeAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4 (Don't use `handleURl...`, just tell the user that you will be opening Safari)

Comment: You should really, really convince your boss to not even try this. If Apple "don't need another fart app", they sure don't need a company bookmark app. Also, it surprises me that Sergey or Larry would even try this. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As others have answered, your app likely won't be approved if this is all that your app is going to do, but to answer your question:

Your problem is that the app is multitasking on iOS 4, and `-[UIApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` doesn't get called again when the app comes back into focus from the background.  (More on how the app delegate methods work with multitasking [here](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/#more-2787).)

If this is all your app is going to do, then the easiest fix is to simply [opt out of multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24).

If you don't opt out, then you need to put that same 'openURL' logic in one of the app delegate methods that gets called when multitasking is used, for instance `-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your sole purpose is to launch a website, there's no need for an app (which Apple wouldn't approve anyways). By simply adding an `apple-touch-icon.png` image to your site's root, anyone can add the site to their home screen and have it look like an app.

http://www.apple.com/webapps/whatarewebapps.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: I don't think that is his sole purpose. His application may require registration before use, which is why I suggested in the comments to alert the user that they will be diverted to a web page.